# Not able to upload the generated .aar file to local maven repository in android studio with gradle build dystem

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I am using android studio with Gradle as build system. I have a library project and application project.

Library - library project.
Application - application project

Gradle and android studio generates .aar files instead of .jar files.
So I wanted to add generated .aar file as a dependency to my application project.

Since there is no support from android studio and gradle wrapper to add .aar files as a dependency for application project, I have tried to upload the .aar file to local maven repository.

The build.gradle code to upload the .aar file to local maven repository is below.

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'android-library'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

 repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }

configurations {
    resultArchives
}

uploadResultArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: 'C:/Users/test/.m2/repository')
        }
    }
}
artifacts{
    resultArchives file: file('build/output/aar/Library-debug.aar')
}
```

Setup info: Android studio1.1.0
Gradle wrapper: 2.2.1

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a gradle pro. But I think this will work:

```
group = 'Library-debug'

uploadArchives{
    repositories{
         mavenDeployer{
             repository(url: uri('C:/Users/test/.m2/repository'))
         }
    }
}
```

Your aar will be available on "C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/[your package name]/Local-debug.aar"